# What does 気持ちの余裕 mean here?

Tags: meaning, translation, phrases

> 唐朽さんと別れた後、仕方が無いのでトイレで着替えを済ませることに。
>
> 肌は若干ベタつくものの、服が濡れているのと濡れていないのでは気持ちの余裕が違う

Context: a character's thought after he dived into a lake, and helped a girl retrieved her handkerchief . Now he had to change clothes in a restroom.

Answer (score 1):

余裕 is "room" or "capacity" for doing things, and 気持ちの is "mental" or "psychological", as opposed to 物理的な ("physically"). The sentence means that if your clothes are wet, it occupies your mind, leaving no mental capacity (or sense of ease) to do anything else.